# How to process comma separated input in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to write one procedure in which there will be table name as an input parameter (Should have only one table at a time) and column names (should have multiple column names comma separated) and column values(should have multiple column names comma separated).

My Attempt:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test_insert(
p_table_name IN VARCHAR2,
p_column_name IN VARCHAR2,-- It can have multiple column names separated by comma 
p_column_value IN VARCHAR2-- It can have multiple column names separated by 
)
AS
lv_str VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
lv_str := 'INSERT INTO '||p_table_name||'should have multiple column names' ||
'VALUES('||'should have multiple column names' ||')';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_str;
END;

Tool used: SQL Developer(18c)
```

I am stuck on how to handle multiple column names and column values inside the procedure body. How will I define an array and proceed accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't. You are setting yourself up to have a procedure that is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

---

If you really want to (please don't):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test_insert(
  p_table_name   IN VARCHAR2,
  p_column_name  IN VARCHAR2,
  p_column_value IN VARCHAR2 
)
AS
  lv_str VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
lv_str := 'INSERT INTO '||p_table_name||' (' || p_column_name || ') VALUES(' || p_column_value ||')';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_str;
END;
/
```

Then you can do:

```sql
BEGIN
  sp_test_insert(
    'my_table',
    'col1, col2, col3',
    q'['a', DATE '2022-05-31', 42]'
  );
END;
/
```

But you can also do:

```sql
BEGIN
  sp_test_insert(
    'my_table',
    'col1, col2, col3',
    q'['a', (SELECT DATE '1970-01-01' FROM secret_table WHERE username = 'Admin' AND password_hash = 'abcgefg1234'), 42]'
  );
END;
/
```

Don't make your application vulnerable to SQL injection attacks; avoid dynamic SQL if you can help it!

---

If you want to make it more resistant to SQL injection attacks then you can use the `DBMS_ASSERT` package:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test_insert(
  p_table_name   IN VARCHAR2,
  p_column_name  IN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST,
  p_column_value IN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST 
)
AS
  lv_str VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  lv_str := 'INSERT INTO '
            || DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME(
                 DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(p_table_name, FALSE)
               )
            ||' ('
            || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(p_column_name(1), FALSE);

  FOR i IN 2 .. p_column_name.COUNT LOOP
    lv_str := lv_str || ', '
                     || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(p_column_name(i), FALSE);
  END LOOP;

  lv_str := lv_str || ') VALUES('
                   || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL(p_column_value(1));

  FOR i IN 2 .. p_column_name.COUNT LOOP
    lv_str := lv_str || ', '
                     || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL(p_column_value(i));
  END LOOP;

  lv_str := lv_str || ')';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_str;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
BEGIN
  sp_test_insert(
    'MY_TABLE',
    SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST( 'COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3'),
    SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST( 'a', '31-MAY-2022', '42')
  );
END;
/
```

However, the values are now all passed into the dynamic SQL statement as strings which makes it more difficult to pass data to `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP` or `INTERVAL` (etc.) columns as it relies on implicit data-type conversions.

You should still avoid dynamic SQL if possible.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=57424e0a7ac92b9633f23a4a289c6859)*

Comment: Is ther any alternatives to acheive this without using dynamic sql

Comment: @Vicky Yes, use `INSERT` statements but don't build them with string concatenation and run them with dynamic SQL. You will need to use the appropriate statement for each table. You can also pass variables in using bind parameters.

Comment: there would be only one table but will have multiple columns and multiple column values. How this can be done ?

Comment: @Vicky Just use a static SQL statement with bind variables: `INSERT INTO table_name ( col1, col2, col3 ) VALUES ( :v1, :v2, :v3 )` If you want to change the number of columns then use a different static statement with more/less columns: `INSERT INTO table_name ( col1, col2, col3, col4 ) VALUES ( :v1, :v2, :v3, :v4 )` (or PL/SQL variables instead of bind variables if you are using PL/SQL). Without a more detailed description of what you are trying to do it is difficult to give better examples.

Comment: Requirement is this only. There will be one stored procedure that will accept table_name, column names, and column values as input parameters. Suppose I gave input parameter name for table_name as ```test_table``` which has say 3 columns out of which user has given only two column names and corresponding two values. Then based on the inputs I need to insert the records in the ```test_table``` which was my first input paramater. Hope this is clear now

Comment: @Vicky If this is a requirement for your job then you should tell whoever set the requirement that it is bad practice and you should **NOT** be doing it like that and you should suggest that they change the requirement. If it is a requirement of a course/university assignment then use any of the queries above but know that your tutor is teaching you bad practice and you should **NEVER** use this in a production environment as you are just creating security issues for your application.

Comment: Okay..Noted Thanks alot.